# Problem with libpython3.6 during installation of htcondor on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: dependencies

I wish to ask for help with the following problem. I am trying to install htcondor on my laptop with ubuntu 19.10. Installation can not start because of the following dependency problem:

```
krzysiek@krzysiek-Lenovo-V330-15IKB:~/Downloads$sudo apt-get install htcondor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 htcondor : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.5) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I think that I installed this package on my computer:

```
krzysiek@krzysiek-Lenovo-V330-15IKB:~/Downloads/Python-3.6.9$ dpkg -l | grep libpython
ii  libpython-dev:amd64                           2.7.17-1                               amd64        header files and a static library for Python2
ii  libpython-stdlib:amd64                        2.7.17-1                               amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (Python2)
ii  libpython2-dev:amd64                          2.7.17-1                               amd64        header files and a static library for Python2
ii  libpython2-stdlib:amd64                       2.7.17-1                               amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (Python2)
ii  libpython2.7:amd64                            2.7.17~rc1-1                           amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-dev:amd64                        2.7.17~rc1-1                           amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-minimal:amd64                    2.7.17~rc1-1                           amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64                     2.7.17~rc1-1                           amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 2.7)
ii  libpython3-dev:amd64                          3.7.5-1                                amd64        header files and a static library for Python (default)
ii  libpython3-stdlib:amd64                       3.7.5-1                                amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
ii  libpython3.6-minimal:amd64                    3.6.9-1~18.04                          amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.6)
ii  libpython3.7:amd64                            3.7.5-2~19.10                          amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 3.7)
ii  libpython3.7-dev:amd64                        3.7.5-2~19.10                          amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v3.7)
ii  libpython3.7-minimal:amd64                    3.7.5-2~19.10                          amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.7)
ii  libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64                     3.7.5-2~19.10                          amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.7)
ii  libpython3.8:amd64                            3.8.0-3~19.10                          amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 3.8)
ii  libpython3.8-minimal:amd64                    3.8.0-3~19.10                          amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.8)
ii  libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64                     3.8.0-3~19.10                          amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.8)

krzysiek@krzysiek-Lenovo-V330-15IKB:~/Downloads$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.9
krzysiek@krzysiek-Lenovo-V330-15IKB:~/Downloads$ python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.5
krzysiek@krzysiek-Lenovo-V330-15IKB:~/Downloads$ python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.0
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I will be thankful for any help.

Trying import sysconfig, import pprint and pprint.pprint(sysconfig.get_config_vars()) I obtained:

```
krzysiek@krzysiek-Lenovo-V330-15IKB:~$ import sysconfig;
import-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PS' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.
krzysiek@krzysiek-Lenovo-V330-15IKB:~$ import pprint;
import-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PS' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.
krzysiek@krzysiek-Lenovo-V330-15IKB:~$ pprint.pprint(sysconfig.get_config_vars())
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `sysconfig.get_config_vars'
```

From Synaptic Package Manager I obtained this communication:
[image: Synaptic]

While from the terminal I am still obtaining the same error what I posted on the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if ubuntu 19.10 has python 3.6 because my fresh installation doesn't show me it. It appears you have installed from third party PPA. Anyway I suggest you to install it with pip. If you need to install `htcondor` for python 3.6 use `python3.6 -m pip install htcondor`. Change `python3.6` to `python3.7` or `python3.8` to install htcondor for these versions of python.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately this also doesn't work for me. I got this WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Comment: Looks like the python version doesn't have SSL module. Show me `import sysconfig; import pprint; pprint.pprint(sysconfig.get_config_vars())` please

Comment: Thank you for your help. I upgraded my answer at the end. I did what you wrote and something doesn't work. After cleaning a little my system and installation of Synaptic Package manager, it occurred that I don't have installed a lot of packages which htcondor needs. The main root of the problem is that I am using Ubuntu 19.10 instead of Ubuntu 18.4, and some packages are simply not installed. But it is strange for me still that when I was trying to use sudo apt-get install htcondor, I obtained only an error, that python is not installed.